# Google Map Not Displaying in Apex Page

Tags: apex, visualforce

I am trying to add simple map in Apex Page. But it is not getting displayed.

```
<apex:page >
<style>
  #map_canvas {
    width: 500px;
    height: 400px;
    background-color: #CCC;
  }
</style>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script>
    function initialize() {
        var map_canvas = document.getElementById('map_canvas');
        var mapOptions = {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(44.5403, -78.5463),
          zoom: 8,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        }        
        var map = new google.maps.Map(map_canvas, map_options);
    }
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

at line `var map = new google.maps.Map(map_canvas, map_options);` change map_options to mapOptions,

Always check for errors in error console when you work with JavaScript.